# Question about rates

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Tom needs $40$ minutes to plough the field. Allen can do in $30$ minutes. If Tom works alone for $10$ minutes and then Allen joins in, how long will it take for them to complete the job?

In $10$ minutes Tom completed $\frac{1}{4}$ of the job.
Together $\frac{1}{40}+\frac{1}{30}= \frac{1}{t}\times\frac{3}{4} $

Where does this equation come from? And what does $\frac{1}{t}$ mean? Where did $\frac{1}{t}$ come from?

Comment: I agree with the answer of infinitylord.  However, apparently, the original problem composer presented his solution somewhat obtusely.  It would have been easier to grasp if the solution had indicated that $$t \times \left[\frac{1}{40} + \frac{1}{30}\right] = \frac{3}{4}.$$  This would indicate that *time* multiplied by *(fraction-of-field/per-minute)* equals *total-amount-of-field-plowed*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On one hand, you know that they plough at a rate of $\frac{1}{40} + \frac{1}{30}$ fields/minute together.

On the other hand, if you let $t$ be the time in minutes that it takes them to plough $\frac{3}{4}$ of a field together, then they plough at a rate of $\frac{3/4}{t}$ fields/minute.

These two rates must be the same, so
$$\frac{1}{40} + \frac{1}{30} = \frac{3/4}{t}$$

Answer (score 1):

I am explaining the answer you provided from a different perspective.

In one minute, Tom completes $\frac{1}{40}th$ of the job and Allen completes $\frac{1}{30}th$ of the job.
Tom works alone for 10 minutes. Which means he completed $\frac{10}{40}th$ of the job, i.e. $\frac{1}{4}th$ of the job and $\frac{3}{4}th$ job is remaining.

When Allen joins, together they work at a combined rate of: $\frac{1}{40} + \frac{1}{30}$. Now we need to make the denominators equal to add them. i.e., $\frac{3}{120} + \frac{4}{120} = \frac{7}{120}$.

Hence, they can together finish 7/120th of the job in one minute.
Therefore, total time required = Total remaining work/ Rate of work per minute = $\frac{\frac{3}{4}}{\frac{7}{120}} = 12.857$ minutes approximately